# Digital Asset management framework

Tags: php, .net, maxscript, dam

I am planning to make a very simple asset management system for 3ds max.

This is how i have planned on making it.

I will be making a webserver on a local network machine.
Will be making a database which stores all the reference to the files stored on the system.
I will be populating all the list from the DB and then will be downloading and importing the files in the application.

I am planning on making the UI and Intermediate layer using maxscript (3dsmax's scripting language) and dotnet.
And at the server end i will be using MySQL and php.

Am i on the correct road or i need to find a different way.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: My studio could help with this work. http://www.thinkingmedia.ca, we do a lot of web development and know 3dsmax very well.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL/PHP is a great combination, and I've used it for years.

With that said.

3dsMax has built support for .NET, and C# would make a better match for your back-end server. You can build websites using C# with the MVC framework that comes with it.

There are also tutorials out there on how to run C# in 3dsMax. That would allow you to connect to the server using C#, send a serialized C# object and respond accordingly.

I think the convenience of having a consistent framework between the two will reduce development time.

Comment: so should i say that the road i chosen to follow is correct and will be enough to achieve this????